# Install modules for a python distribution included in another software installation

Tags: python

I'm trying to run batches of simulations in Ansys. I have a post solve python script that runs to pull the data I want from the simulation and save it before running the next one. However, I want to be able to manipulate the data in excel in this post solve script, meaning I want to use openpyxl. However, I can't figure out how to install the module for the python distribution included in the Ansys installation. I already have it installed for my main Python distribution.

Python is installed here: C:\Users\jaw195\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

And the Ansys Python is installed here: C:\Apps\ANSYS Inc\v202\commonfiles\CPython\3_7\winx64\Release\python

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I have TWO Python distributions installed. One I installed myself, the other was installed as part of the Ansys installation. I want to be able to install modules for the Ansys distribution, but can't as using `pip install <module>` installs for the distribution I installed myself.

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to install a module, but you can't because it's already installed... so what's the actual issue? I mean, which error message to you get for which command (not the installation, but the use of this module that seems supposed to be already installed)? Btw do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: @Christophe the error I get is no module found. The problem is that the module is installed for my installed Python, but not for the Ansys included Python. And I do use virtual environment but I don't believe this would help here, I can't control how Ansys runs Python